# How Can I Change an ItemsPanelTemplate in Code Behind?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

```
<ItemsControl>        
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

If I want to change the ItemsPanelTemplate from the default (StackPanel) to a Grid, I do the above in XAML.  How could I achieve the same thing in code?

I read this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemspaneltemplate) but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Not trying to be rude; just that what you are asking is not really how WPF was intended to work.

Comment: Well it's not WPF, it's UWP.  And I'm creating a custom control in C# that inherits ItemsControl and places each child in a radial pattern based on an algorithm.  The template must always be a Grid, it cannot be a StackPanel.

Comment: Either way; that kind of code-behind shenanigans isn't usually the ideal way. If you are creating a custom control couldn't you just put your XAML into the control template and call it good?

Comment: Every custom control I've seen on NuGet contains a C# file.

Comment: Sure; they all have C# files. That's where you set up dependency properties, event handlers, etc. (you also need a `class` inheriting `Control` for the whole thing to work.) The classic way to define a piece of the visual tree has always been through the control template though.

Comment: If you always want a Grid as the ItemsPanel, you can just define it in your custom control's default style inside Generic.xaml.

Comment: Except I wouldn't even need a XAML if not for this one thing, but ok.  Every similar control I've seen such as these: https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls are C# files.  The XAML is a just an optional resourcedictionary with styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd prefer to do this in the default style of the custom control inside *Generic.xaml*, but if you want a pure C# way, here is how it can be done -

```
private void ApplyGridAsItemsPanel()
{
    MyItemsControl.ItemsPanel = ParseItemsPanelTemplate(typeof(Grid));

    ItemsPanelTemplate ParseItemsPanelTemplate(Type panelType)
    {
        var itemsPanelTemplateXaml =
            $@"<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                                  xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
                   <{panelType.Name} />
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>";

        return (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Load(itemsPanelTemplateXaml);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I understand this is unconventional and there's a very good chance I'll take that advice.  I didn't realize this would involve actual xaml syntax in the c# file, which I agree is ridiculous.